# Loader is not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I have created one page in office 365 site. I have put loader inside that. Now loader is working perfectly in firefox but not working in IE and Chrome.

Loader is not visible. I have tried following option:
1. through hide/show method

```
 $('.className').hide();
 $('.className').show();
```

**2. through css**

```
$('.className').css('display', 'none');

$('.className').css('display', 'block');
```

**3. through class**

```
$('.className').addClass('classBlock');

$('.className').removeClass('classBlock');
```

In css I have tried both options:

```
display:none/block;

visibility: hidden/visible
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code to your page top:

```
<div style="display: none" id="dvloader">
    <img class="loader"      src="localhost/web/themes/default/images/meneloading.gif"/>
</div>
```

Make button on page the button class should be (class="rateSearch"):

```
$('body').on('click','.rateSearch',function(){
    $("#dvloader").show();
    showDetails();});
showDetails(){// your calculations or anything
    $("#dvloader").hide();}
```

Comment: I have did same as you have given..Gireesh T